# Como enviar dados do banco de dados para a view usando ajax com codeigniter 3

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Olá! Estou com uma dúvida. Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para uma loja de móveis. Quero fazer com que o dono edite os móveis que ele cadastrou no sistema. Consigo recuperar os dados, mas não consigo colocá-los nos campos de uma janela modal

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A janela de edição será esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Consigo recuperar os dados do banco via ajax e via segmentos do codeigniter. Mas o problema é colocá-los nesses campos.

```js
$("#editarProduto").click(function(){
  var id = $("table#tabelaEstoque tbody .colorir td:first").text();
  if(id) {
   $.ajax({
    url: "HomeSistema/editarProduto/"+ id,
    data: {id:id},
    type: "post",
    dataType: "text",
    beforeSend: function() {
     $(".loadWateEditProduto").show();
    }
   }).done(function(dataProduto){
    window.alert(dataProduto);
    $("#editarProdutoEstoque").show();
    $(".loadWateEditProduto").hide();
   }).fail(function(){
    $("section#erroInternoEstoque").show();
    $(".loadWateEditProduto").hide();
   });
  }
  else
   $("#selectProduto").show();
 });
```

Código php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class HomeSistema extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->helper("form");
        $this->load->helper("date");
    }

    public function index()
    {
        if($this->session->has_userdata("nome")) {
            #listar usuários
            $this->load->model("recuperarUsuariosModel");
            $dados['usuarios'] = $this->recuperarUsuariosModel->recuperaUsuarios();

            # lista produtos
            $this->load->model("recuperaProdutosModel");
            $dados['produtos'] = $this->recuperaProdutosModel->recuperaProdutos();

            # listar Clientes
            $this->load->model("recuperaClientesModel");
            $dados['clientes'] = $this->recuperaClientesModel->recuperaClientes();

            $this->load->view("sistema/homeSistema-v",$dados);
        } else {
            redirect("login", "location");
        }
    }

    public function editarProduto() {
        $idProduto = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->load->model("RecuperaProdutosModel");
        $produtos['produto'] = $this->RecuperaProdutosModel->recuperaProdutosEdicao($idProduto);
        $this->load->view("sistema/homeSistema-v",$produtos);
    }
```

Como faço para editar os dados trazidos do banco? já tentei com segmentos e via post.

Comment: So pra mim entender correto. Voçe quer saber como colocar os dados recebidos no formulario?

Comment: Tudo em `modal`? Sério mesmo? Qual é a necessidade disso?

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro sua lógica esta confusa, vamos por partes:

1. Crie uma função que retorne um JSON com os dados do produtos, somente os dados.
2. Utilize a função ***.on('click')*** para carregar os valores dentro dos inputs: `$('#nomeProduto').val(respostaProduto.nomeProduto);`
3. Após feito isso com todos os dados, você deve captar novamente estes dados assim que o cliente clicar em salvar, deve-se enviar estes dados a uma nova função para realizar o update no banco de dados e retornar a reposta de sucesso ou erro.
4. Através de ***Ajax*** atualizar a tabela dos produtos com os novos valores.

Pronto hehe.

Obs: Eu gosto de usar o `$.post(UrlFunção,dados,function(data){'sucesso'},tipodeDado);`

Answer (score 0):

Como eu faria:

no meu botão colocaria o id do produto com o atributo 'data-' dessa forma:

```
<button id="editarProduto" data-produto-id="<?php echo $produto['id']; ?>">
</button>
```

No js eu usaria o $.post que é mais simples, assim:

```
$("#editarProduto").click(function() {

    event.preventDefault();

    var produtoId = $(this).data('produto-id');

    $.post("HomeSistema/editarProduto", {
        produtoId: produtoId
    }, function(retorno) {
        $(".loadWateEditProduto").html(retorno);
        $(".loadWateEditProduto").show();
    });
});
```

no construtor faria assim:

```
public function editarProduto()
{
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
    $this->load->model("RecuperaProdutosModel");
    $produtos['produto'] = $this->RecuperaProdutosModel->recuperaProdutosEdicao($post['produtoId']);
    $this->load->view("sistema/editar-produto-modal",$produtos);
}
```

*você precisaria ter uma view apenas para o modal